# Как я могу во vuex передать объект события через `dispatch`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события, vuex, javascript-events

Если передавать, например, через стрелочную функцию, то всё работает, но тогда я не могу удалить слушателя через `removeEventListener`.

```
export const actions = {
  open() {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('open')
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.dispatch('clickListener', e))
  },
  close() {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('open')
    document.removeEventListener('click', (e) => this.dispatch('clickListener', e))
  },
  toggle() {
    if (document.querySelector('nav').classList.contains('open')) {
      this.dispatch('close')
    } else {
      this.dispatch('open')
    }
  },
  clickListener(ctx, e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
}
```

Comment: Я думал меня ничем не удивить... Зачем с архитектурной точки зрения Вам нужно хранить во Vuex обработчик ивентов?

Comment: чтобы его могли вызывать разные компоненты, дабы в каждом из них не писать функцию закрытия открытого элемента при клике не на этот элемент, у вас есть решение?

Comment: Вы решаете не те проблемы, не теми инструментами. Если вам нужно отслеживать одно и то же событие в разных компонентах, сделайте компонент обертку, или воспользуйтесь миксинами. кроме директив у Вас нигде не должно быть необходимости получать доступ к DOM. Ответить на Ваш вопрос сложно по тому что Ваш подход неверен.

Comment: покажите как делается компонент обёртка?